# Doctrine2 ORA-01722: Nombre non valide

Tags: php, sql, oracle, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have an entity Marks that contains the "Result" in float :

```
/**
 * @var float
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="RESULT", type="float", nullable=false)
 */
private $result;
```

Here is the column in the form

```
->add('result', 'choice', array(
            'choices' => array(
                '1' => '1.0',
                '1.5' => '1.5',
                '2' => '2.0',
                '2.5' => '2.5',
                '3' => '3.0',
                '3.5' => '3.5',
                '4' => '4.0', 
                '4.5' => '4.5',
                '5' => '5.0',
                '5.5' => '5.5',
                '6' => '6.0'
            ),
            'label' => 'Result',
        ))
```

I tried not to put quotes in the array but it changes nothing.

When I try to add a a mark with a decimal ( for example 5.5 ) I get the following error :

```
An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO APPRENTICE_MARK (COEFFICIENT, ID, RESULT, FK_BRANCH, FK_YEAR, FK_MARKTYPE) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params [2, 97, "3.5", "27", "2", "2"]:
```

So I tried to change the setter to

```
/**
 * Set result
 *
 * @param float $result
 * @return ApprenticeMark
 */
public function setResult($result)
{
    $this->result = floatval($result);

    return $this;
}
```

But I get the same error just without the quotes on 3.5

```
An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO APPRENTICE_MARK (COEFFICIENT, ID, RESULT, FK_BRANCH, FK_YEAR, FK_MARKTYPE) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params [2, 97, 3.5, "27", "2", "2"]:
```

Here is the controller part :

```
            $mark = new ApprenticeMark();
    $form = $this->createForm(new ApprenticeMarkType(), $mark);

    $request = $this->get('request');
    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
            $form->bind($request);
            if ($form->isValid()) {
                    $m->persist($mark);
                    $m->flush();
                    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('grids_apprentice_index',array('idApprentice' => $apprentice->getId())));
            }
    }
```

The problem doesn't come from my Oracle db, I run with no errors on Oracle SQL Developer:

```
INSERT INTO APPRENTICE_MARK (COEFFICIENT, ID, RESULT, FK_BRANCH, FK_YEAR, FK_MARKTYPE) VALUES ('1', '101', 5.5, '27', '2', '2');
```

Do you know how to solve this problem ?

Regards

Comment: How are the bind variables being assigned? I think I understand the first statement erroring, but not the second, unless it's still setting the values with `setString()` (or whatever the equivalent is for your stack). The short explanation is your session's `NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS` value.

Comment: I bind the variables inside the controller, I just added it to my post.

Comment: OK, I'm not sure how that relates to the inert bind variables (how `?` maps to each value, the `3.5` for example). If it was set as a float this would work OK I think. It seems to be being set as a string, so the database is converting it to a number using your session NLS settings, and those expect `,` as the decimal separator. Unfortunately I have no idea how to approach that in this stack. But it seems like your values as using `.` intentionally, so just changing your operating system locale to English might work around it? Sorry, can't be more specific as I don't use PHP...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your answer, you're saying that my OS causes the problem ? I work on a Windows 7 with Wamp and the database is on a remote linux server.

Comment: When I make the query directly in Oracle SQL Developer with : INSERT INTO APPRENTICE_MARK (COEFFICIENT, ID, RESULT, FK_BRANCH, FK_YEAR, FK_MARKTYPE) VALUES ('1', '101', 5.5, '27', '2', '2'); It works. But Doctrine2 does the "ORA-01722: Nombre non valide" error

Comment: What the hell, it works with a "," instead of the "." Thank you very much !

Comment: Yes, that's what the session `NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS` affects. Your session is expecting a comma as the decimal separator, but you were passing a period. But that only matters if Oracle is doing an (implicit) `to_number()` from a string; if you were passing it as a number it wouldn't matter. So I think something slightly odd is happening under the hood here, and you're relying on the client session always having the locale you have now. Which may be OK, but better avoided if possible.

Comment: Ok so when I did the floatval() which transforms a string to a float it should have worked ?! The NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS is set by the machine that hosts the website ? Thank you !

Comment: But I don't know how that float value is being passed across; since it errors it seems to be sent as a string. As I said, I don't know the PHP side, never mind your other tools, well enough to know where or why that's happening, or if it's normal. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't address the best way to avoid the issue in your PHP/Doctrine2/etc. stack, it's just an attempt to demonstrate what's happening on the database side.

The decimal separator character is determined by the session's [`NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS` setting](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17110/initparams150.htm). Since your error message is in French, I'll assume your `NLS_TERRITORY` is `FRANCE`, which defaults the decimal character to `,` and group character to `.` You can verify that for a particular session with:

```
select value from nls_session_parameters
where parameter = 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS';
```

When you use a string literal in place of a numeric value an implicit `to_char()` conversion is done, and the NLS setting affects how the string is interpreted. If your string value has a period but your NLS settings expect a comma it will error:

```
alter session set nls_territory = 'UNITED KINGDOM';

session SET altered.

INSERT INTO APPRENTICE_MARK (COEFFICIENT, ID, RESULT, FK_BRANCH, FK_YEAR, FK_MARKTYPE)
VALUES ('1', '101', '5.5', '27', '2', '2');

1 rows inserted.

alter session set nls_territory = 'FRANCE';

session SET altered.

INSERT INTO APPRENTICE_MARK (COEFFICIENT, ID, RESULT, FK_BRANCH, FK_YEAR, FK_MARKTYPE)
VALUES ('1', '101', '5.5', '27', '2', '2');

Error starting at line : 28 in command -
INSERT INTO APPRENTICE_MARK (COEFFICIENT, ID, RESULT, FK_BRANCH, FK_YEAR, FK_MARKTYPE)
VALUES ('1', '101', '5.5', '27', '2', '2')
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-01722: invalid number
01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
```

Having them them mismatched the other way errors as well, of course:

```
alter session set nls_territory = 'UNITED KINGDOM';

session SET altered.

INSERT INTO APPRENTICE_MARK (COEFFICIENT, ID, RESULT, FK_BRANCH, FK_YEAR, FK_MARKTYPE)
VALUES ('1', '101', '5,5', '27', '2', '2');

Error starting at line : 48 in command -
INSERT INTO APPRENTICE_MARK (COEFFICIENT, ID, RESULT, FK_BRANCH, FK_YEAR, FK_MARKTYPE)
VALUES ('1', '101', '5,5', '27', '2', '2')
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-01722: invalid number
01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"

alter session set nls_territory = 'FRANCE';

session SET altered.

INSERT INTO APPRENTICE_MARK (COEFFICIENT, ID, RESULT, FK_BRANCH, FK_YEAR, FK_MARKTYPE)
VALUES ('1', '101', '5,5', '27', '2', '2');

1 rows inserted.
```

If you insert a number, not a string, then you always have to use a period regardless of your NLS settings, since the comma is always a value separator:

```
alter session set nls_territory = 'UNITED KINGDOM';

session SET altered.

INSERT INTO APPRENTICE_MARK (COEFFICIENT, ID, RESULT, FK_BRANCH, FK_YEAR, FK_MARKTYPE)
VALUES ('1', '101', 5.5, '27', '2', '2');

1 rows inserted.

INSERT INTO APPRENTICE_MARK (COEFFICIENT, ID, RESULT, FK_BRANCH, FK_YEAR, FK_MARKTYPE)
VALUES ('1', '101', 5,5, '27', '2', '2');

Error starting at line : 67 in command -
INSERT INTO APPRENTICE_MARK (COEFFICIENT, ID, RESULT, FK_BRANCH, FK_YEAR, FK_MARKTYPE)
VALUES ('1', '101', 5,5, '27', '2', '2')
Error at Command Line : 67 Column : 13
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00913: too many values
00913. 00000 -  "too many values"
```

And:

```
alter session set nls_territory = 'FRANCE';

session SET altered.

INSERT INTO APPRENTICE_MARK (COEFFICIENT, ID, RESULT, FK_BRANCH, FK_YEAR, FK_MARKTYPE)
VALUES ('1', '101', 5.5, '27', '2', '2');

1 rows inserted.

INSERT INTO APPRENTICE_MARK (COEFFICIENT, ID, RESULT, FK_BRANCH, FK_YEAR, FK_MARKTYPE)
VALUES ('1', '101', 5,5, '27', '2', '2');

Error starting at line : 77 in command -
INSERT INTO APPRENTICE_MARK (COEFFICIENT, ID, RESULT, FK_BRANCH, FK_YEAR, FK_MARKTYPE)
VALUES ('1', '101', 5,5, '27', '2', '2')
Error at Command Line : 77 Column : 13
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00913: too many values
00913. 00000 -  "too many values"
```

So back to your PHP insert. Even when you have `5.5` as a `float`, you're getting the ORA-01722 value. Therefore it must still be being passed to Oracle as a string, and the session's NLS parameters are causing the confusion. When you pass `'5,5'` instead it's working because your session is expecting a comma.

Assuming you aren't (yet) setting the NLS parameters somewhere in the PHP stack, Oracle will inherit your operating systems's locale in some way; you're running on a French-speaking machine (I assume) so you have to use commas as decimal separators. But someone running exactly the same code on an English-speaking machine will now get that error, unless the commas are changed back to periods. So you're avoiding the problem, not really solving it.

Ideally you'd pass a plain number across so no conversion was necessary in the DB. It isn't clear why that isn't happening. Your query has bind variables (from `VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)`) so it seems that the binding is being done with strings. Even when you set it to be a float it's still a string when Oracle sees it. I don't know why - I don't know enough about PHP - but I'd look at how the variables are set, and maybe dig into how Doctrine2 handles bind variables. You could probably explicitly set up NLS from PHP so it's consistent regardless of your machine locale. Someone with more PHP knowledge will have to help you find a sustainable fix or workaround...